# Occurrence of an element in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to get the frequency of each value in a given `list`.

```py
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "apple", "banana"]
counts = [fruits.count(x) for x in fruits]
print(counts)
>>> [2, 2, 1, 2, 2] # "apple", "banana", "cherry", "apple", "banana"
```

**Desired Output**

```py
>>> [2, 2, 1] # "apple", "banana", "cherry"
```

---

Secondly; what might be the most computationally efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Sorry on wording of title. I may need to rephrase it better shortly

Comment: try looking into `Counter`

Comment: Oh ok, I'll do so to continue trying a working solution. I am however interested in doing this on a rather large scale; and so was hoping to use *primitive* Python code instead to make this quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

[*Counter(fruits).values()]
# [2, 2, 1]
```

This collects all counts in a single iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `set(fruits)` to remove duplicates and then count the elements from the fruits list:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "apple", "banana"]
set_fruits = set(fruits)
counts = [fruits.count(x) for x in set_fruits]
print(counts)
```

Comment: `fruits.count(x)` is not a good idea, you are traversing the list again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a dict and count the frequency.

```py
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "apple", "banana"]
counter_map = {}

for each_fruit in fruits:
    if each_fruit in counter_map:
        counter_map[each_fruit] += 1
    else:
        counter_map[each_fruit] = 1
        
print(list(counter_map.values())) #[2, 2, 1]
```

Comment: You've reinvented `collections.Counter`.

Comment: I understand your pun, but I sometimes feel heading over the black boxes to newcomers may not do much good without doing things from basic things. I might be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Using dictionary to count the frequency

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "apple", "banana"]
freq = {}
for fruit in fruits:
    freq[fruit] = freq.get(fruit,0) + 1
print(list(freq.values()))
```